# Numerical Analysis of Differential Equation with Boundary Conditions

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, numerical-methods, finite-differences

**Note**

> I have decided to edit this post so it is more specific and also
> because I was incorrect the first time. I didn't wanna make another
> post about the same subject, but if this is not allowed then put a
> comment below and I will repost the original, thanks for your time.

The temperature distribution $T(r)$ within the cylinder wall ($1 \leq r \leq 2$) is determined by the differential equation:

$$
r \frac{d^2T}{dr^2} + \frac{dT}{dr} = 0 \quad 
$$ The outer side of the pipeline, at $r = 2$, is cooled by the surrounding air with a temperature of $Te = 20^\circ$C.
$$
k \frac{dT}{dr} = -\alpha(T - T_e) \quad \text{at } r = 2 \quad 
$$ a) Discretize the equation using central finite differences for $N = 4$. Use boundary conditions and print out the system matrix and the right-hand side with all elements. The derivative in the boundary condition at $r = 2$ can be approximated using a first-order difference approximation:

$$
k \frac{T_{N+1} - T_{N}}{h} = -\alpha(T_{N} - T_{e}).
$$
Use this boundary condition to eliminate $T_{N+1}$ in the last equation of the equation system. Let k = $\alpha$ = 1

This is basically the problem summerized and I got to this linear equation:
$$\begin{bmatrix} \frac{-2r}{h^2} && \frac{2r+h}{2h^2} && 0 \\ \frac{2r-h}{2h^2} && \frac{-2r}{h^2} && \frac{2r+h}{2h^2} \\ 0 && \frac{2r-h}{2h^2} && \frac{ah}{k}-\frac{2r}{h^2}-1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} T{1} \\ T{2} \\ T{3} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}  -T_0\frac{2r-h}{2*h^2} \\ 0 \\ T{e}\frac{ah}{k} \end{bmatrix}$$

Btw $T_{e}$ is the temperature outside which is 20 and $T_0$ is inside witch is 450, is this equation wrong because I keep getting incorrect result when I solve for the vector T. I have been stuck at this problem because no matter what I do I can't get it right. The problem is larger than this but it builds upon it so if I am correct here then I should be there too.

Comment: You have accidentally posted the same question twice.

Comment: It must have been a bug or something because I have no idea how it is posted 2 times. I am curious how this happened now haha. FYI the other one is deleted now, thanks for the reminder.

Comment: Write out the PDE discretization at $T_N$. It should contain $T_{N-1}$, $T_N$, and $T_{N+1}$. Use the discretization you wrote for the boundary condition to solve for $T_{N+1}$, then plug it into the PDE discretization at $T_N$. You will then have an expression only involving $T_{N-1}$ and $T_N$ and a bit of extra stuff on the RHS.

Comment: Isn't what I am doing correct tho? I feel like the last row in the matrix is PDE discretization at $T_N$ you are describing. Anyways I still don't really understand how I can solve for $T_{N+1}$.